# What is the nuance between these electrical parameters in this load cell datasheet?

Tags: datasheet, load-cell

A load cell has the following specs:

[image]

I've highlighted the relevant part in yellow. There are two parameters called Uref and Bu. Both of them is about the excitation voltage for the Wheatstone bridge inside the load cell. But I couldn't conclude which voltage I can or should use as the excitation voltage. Can someone describe these parameters more explicitly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reference voltage was the voltage used for testing or calibrating the device.

The nominal range is the range of "working" voltage you can expect the device to work between.

Answer (score 0):

In the absence of any other major constraints, use the Reference excitation voltage. Most of the datasheet will apply directly and you can be confident of itts accuracy.

Given other constraints, use other voltages within the working range ... e.g. extremely tight power budget? reduce excitation voltage, but not below 0.5Vrms. But be aware you may have to interpret other specs such as noise in light of the changed voltage.